# MySQL UPDATE statement is not updating database data through web form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

**Scenario:** I have a web form where the user can manually enter data (see below). The user will submit the form and the data will be automatically added to the database.

```
date, order_ref, first_name, last_name, postcode, country, quantity, scott_packing, packing_price, courier_price, dispatch_type, job_status
```

On another page, the user will be able to only view all the jobs that are currently being (this data is taken from the database) processed and add the tracking number and edit the `packing_price,courier_price and job_status` and submit the new data.

http://i754.photobucket.com/albums/xx182/rache_R/Screenshot2014-04-23at104045_zps2a628d50.png

**Issue:** When the user clicks the 'submit all' button, the user is supposed to be redirected to the thank you page which simply notifies the user that their entry has been successful however at the moment, the user is only directed to a blank page which contains the navigation menu. I have checked the database to see if the data has been updated but nothing has changed. How do i get my update statement to work so that the user can update the existing jobs?

This is the code for the page that displays all the jobs:

```
        <?
session_start();

if(!session_is_registered(myusername))
{
    header("location:../index.php");
}

include("../template/header.php");
include("../controllers/cn.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Jobs";
$qry = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<div class='content'>";
echo "<form class='form_edit' method='post' action='updatejob.php'>";
echo "<table id='job_list' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<th>Job No</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Qty</th>
<th>Postcode</th>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Packed by Scott</th>
<th>Packing Price</th>
<th>Courier Price</th>
<th>Tracking No</th>
<th>Dispatch Type</th>
<th>Job Status</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='80' style='text-align: center;'>" . $row['order_ref'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='100' style='text-align: center;'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='100' style='text-align: center;'>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='100' style='text-align: center;'>" . $row['postcode'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='100' style='text-align: center;'>" . $row['country'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='100' style='text-align: center;'><input type='CHECKBOX' id='scott_packing' name='scott_packing' value='". $row['scott_packing'] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td width='100' style='text-align: center;'><input type='text' id='packing_price' name='packing_price' value='".  $row['packing_price'] . "'/></td>";
    echo "<td width='100' style='text-align: center;'><input type='text' id='courier_price' name='courier_price' value='". $row['courier_price']."'/></td>";
    echo "<td width='100' style='text-align: center;'><input type='text' id='tracking_number' name='tracking_number' value='". $row['tracking_number'] . "'/></td>";
    echo "<td width='100' style='text-align: center;'>" . $row['dispatch_type'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='100' style='text-align: center;'><select name='job_status' id='job_status'>
        <option value='". $row['job_status'] ."'>". $row['job_status']. " <option value='dispatched'>Dispatched</td>";   

    //echo "<td width='100' style='text-align: center;'><a href='editjob.php'>edit</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit all'/>";
echo "</form>";

mysql_close();


?>
```

And here is the code that is supposed to update the data:

```
    <?
session_start();

if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:../index.php");

}

include("../template/header.php");
include("../controllers/cn.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $order_ref = $_POST['order_ref'];
    $packing_price = $_POST['packing_price'];
    $courier_price = $_POST['courier_price'];
    $tracking_number = $_POST['tracking_number'];
    $job_status = $_POST['job_status'];

    $sql_qry = "UPDATE Jobs SET '$packing_price, $courier_price, $tracking_number, $job_status' WHERE order_ref = '$order_ref'";

    $query = mysql_query($sql_query);

      if(!$query)
    {
        die('Could not update data' .mysql_error());
    } else
    {
        header("location: updatesuccess.php");
        exit;
    }

    mysql_close();

}




?>
```

Comment: your update syntax is wrong. you should use: `"UPDATE Jobs SET packingpricecoloumnname='$packing_price', [..] WHERE order_ref = '$order_ref'";`. In a nutshell, you're updating a row without refering which coloumns should be updated :). Also, please take care that mysql_* is deprecated. You may use, for security reasons, either Mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: the `name` attributes for the `input` tags are missing.

Comment: @RolandJansen Thanks i have now added the name attribute to my inputs

Comment: @briosheje So it seems to be returning something now but it says this "Could not update dataQuery was empty"

Comment: @user3519721: if the data is empty then you should log and find out what variables are empty or not even set (perhaps).

Comment: @briosheje i think the issue is the order_ref, it is appearing as empty. I am trying to make sure that when the data is updated, it updates the correct jobs therefore, i need the order_ref

Comment: @user3519721: the order_ref must be empty, since you're not refering to any input or select or anything with it's name. You should add `name` tags to your `input` tags, as Roland Jansed said :]

Comment: @briosheje i have updated my code with the input names etc :) the order ref is being pulled out from my database so it has data inside it

Answer (score 0):

Your update query is wrong. The query of update should be like

```
UPDATE table_name SET field1=new-value1, field2=new-value2
[WHERE Clause]
```

In this case it will be something like

```
UPDATE Jobs SET packing_price='$packing_price',courier_price='$courier_price',tracking_number='$tracking_number',job_status='job_status' WHERE order_ref = '$order_ref'";
```

and also you missed out the name property for input fields. If you don't specify it you can't access it like  `$_POST['packing_price']` where `packing_price` is be the `name` of the input field.

Also add `method="post"` to the form like

```
echo "<form class='form_edit' action='updatejob.php' method='post'>";
```

Comment: thank you for spotting this. I didn't realise i missed out the post method :) @Jenz

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query

```
$sql_qry = "UPDATE Jobs SET column1 = '$packing_price', column2 ='$courier_price', .... WHERE order_ref = '$order_ref'";
```

And like Roland Jansen stated you are missing the name attributes on your input tags